# How to replace string only once without regex in Java?

Tags: java, string

I need to replace a dynamic substring withing a larger string, but only once (i.e. first match). The String class provides only `replace()`, which replaces ALL instances of the substring; there is a `replaceFirst()` method but it only takes regexp instead of a regular string. I have two concerns with using regex:

1) my substring is dynamic, so might contain weird characters that mean something else in regex, and I don't want deal with character escaping.

2) this replacement happens very often, and I'm not sure whether using regex will impact performance. I can't compile the regex beforehand since the regex itself is dynamic!

I must be missing something here since this seems to me is a very basic thing... Is there a replaceFirst method taking regular string somewhere else in the java franework?

Comment: Your second concern may be valid, but as for your first point: you can use Pattern.quote to construct a regex that will literally match a given string. That is, it'll deal with the escaping for you.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `bigString.indexof(smallString)` to get the index of the first occurrence of the small string in the big one (or -1 if none, in which case you're done).  Then, use `bigString.substring` to get the pieces of the big string before and after the match, and finally `concat` to put those before and after pieces back together, with your intended replacement in the middle.

Comment: amen - this answer demonstrates a key principle of s/w development:  just because you have a tool, doesn't mean you have to use it.  I can't tell you how many times I see mid-level programmers sort  list to find the smallest element.

Comment: That's a good comment. But note that this manual approach takes several lines of code, which may require comments and unit tests to avoid bugs. Using a single line `replaceFirst' call is clearer and less error-prone, even though it may also be slower at runtime. Don't optimise prematurely.

Comment: I am amazed that there is not be a simple library function encoding the complex algorithm mentioned! See this for example (python): http://stackoverflow.com/a/4628646/243233

Answer (score 34):

You should use already tested and well documented libraries in favor of writing your own code!

```
StringUtils.replaceOnce("aba", "a", "")    = "ba"
```

The `StringUtils` class is from [Apache Commons Lang3](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) package and can be imported in Maven like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: you are suggesting to include a whole library for a simple string replacement .  Do you think it's worth?   Forget about whether it;s worth or not.. Isn't it weird that just for a simple functionality , I have to go for a new library altogether.

Answer (score 31):

As Laurence suggested, you can use `Pattern.quote` like this:

```
newString = string.replaceFirst(Pattern.quote(substring),
                                Matcher.quoteReplacement(replacement));
```

`quote` creates a regex that literally matches the substring, and `quoteReplacement` creates a literal replacement string.

Another approach is simply to compile the substring as a literal regex like this:

```
newString = Pattern.compile(substring, Pattern.LITERAL).
        matcher(string).replaceFirst(Matcher.quoteReplacement(replacement));
```

This might be slightly more efficient, but also a bit less clear.

You could also do it manually, since you're only wanting to replace the first occurrence. But regexes are pretty efficient, so don't optimise prematurely!

Comment: this fails to mention that the replacement also needs to be quoted.

Comment: @Clashsoft Good point (also made by others) - I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 7):

make sure to also replace `\s` and `$s` in the replacement as well. This is probably what you want because you can't have any subgroups with yours `()`'s being removed).

```
newStr = str.replaceFirst(Pattern.quote(target), Matcher.quoteReplacement(replacement));
```

Comment: You have a good point here, but you don't directly answer to the question. It would be more appropriate as a comment on Bennet McElwee's answer.

Answer (score 4):

### Solution with `Pattern`

You could also change the [String.replace](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-) method that uses the **literal** interpretation of characters to replace only the first occurrence of the `target` character sequence:

```
/**
 * Replaces the first subsequence of the <tt>source</tt> character sequence
 * that matches the literal target sequence with the specified literal
 * replacement sequence.
 * 
 * @param source source sequence on which the replacement is made
 * @param target the sequence of char values to be replaced
 * @param replacement the replacement sequence of char values
 * @return the resulting string
 */
private static String replaceFirst1(CharSequence source, CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement) {
    return Pattern.compile(target.toString(), Pattern.LITERAL).matcher(
        source).replaceFirst(Matcher.quoteReplacement(replacement.toString()));
}
```

From the documentation of [Pattern.LITERAL](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#LITERALy):

> When this flag is specified then the input string that specifies the pattern is treated as a sequence of literal characters. **Metacharacters or escape sequences in the input sequence will be given no special meaning.**

### Solution without `Pattern`

The other and more efficient way, of course, is to use [Alex Martelli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/95810/alex-martelli)'s hint to produce the following functionality:

```
/**
 * Replaces the first subsequence of the <tt>source</tt> string that matches
 * the literal target string with the specified literal replacement string.
 * 
 * @param source source string on which the replacement is made
 * @param target the string to be replaced
 * @param replacement the replacement string
 * @return the resulting string
 */
private static String replaceFirst2(String source, String target, String replacement) {
    int index = source.indexOf(target);
    if (index == -1) {
        return source;
    }

    return source.substring(0, index)
        .concat(replacement)
        .concat(source.substring(index+target.length()));
}
```

### Time measurement

Based on 10 runs, the `replaceFirst2` method executes about **5 times faster** than the `replaceFirst1` method. I have put both of these methods in a loop with 100.000 repeats and got the following results, in milliseconds:

```
    Method                 Results (in ms)             Average
replaceFirst1: 220 187 249 186 199 211 172 199 281 199 | 210
replaceFirst2:  40  39  58  45  48  40  42  42  43  59 |  45
```

Answer (score 1):

StringBuilder class in java can be used very easily to do a non-regex based replacement of one string with another.

```
private static String replace(String in, String ths, String that) {
    
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(in);

    int idx = sb.indexOf(ths); 
    
    while (idx > -1) {
        sb.replace(idx, idx + ths.length(), that);
        idx = sb.indexOf(ths);
    }
    
    return sb.toString(); 
    
}
```

Comment: this does the same as `String.replace`, i.e. replace all occurrences

Comment: @Clashsoft replace `while` loop with `if` condition then it will replace only the first occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

Pattern.quote does not seem to work in all cases. Try `Pattern.quote(":-)");

Comment: That would be more fitted as a comment to the Laurent Gonsalves's comment on the question or on Bennet McElwee's answer than as a separate answer, since you don't address the question itself.