# Replace first occurrence of string in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have some sample string. How can I replace first occurrence of this string in a longer string with empty string?

```
regex = re.compile('text')
match = regex.match(url)
if match:
    url = url.replace(regex, '')
```

Comment: What are you searching and replacing? What's in that `url`?

Comment: I want to replace first occurence of 'text' in my url string

Answer (score 367, accepted):

string [replace()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace) function perfectly solves this problem:

> string.replace(s, old, new[, maxreplace])
>
> Return a copy of string s with all occurrences of substring old replaced by new. If the optional argument maxreplace is given, the first maxreplace occurrences are replaced.

```
>>> u'longlongTESTstringTEST'.replace('TEST', '?', 1)
u'longlong?stringTEST'
```

Answer (score 25):

Use [`re.sub`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub) directly, this allows you to specify a `count`:

```
regex.sub('', url, 1)
```

(Note that the order of arguments is `replacement`, `original` not the opposite, as might be suspected.)