# Replace first occurrence only of a string?

Tags: python, string, replace

I have something like this:

```
text = 'This text is very very long.'
replace_words = ['very','word']

for word in replace_words:
    text = text.replace('very','not very')
```

I would like to only replace the first 'very' or choose which 'very' gets overwritten. I'm doing this on much larger amounts of text so I want to control how duplicate words are being replaced.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace first occurrence of string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628618/replace-first-occurrence-of-string-in-python)

Answer (score 175):

```
text = text.replace("very", "not very", 1)
```

```
>>> help(str.replace)
Help on method_descriptor:

replace(...)
    S.replace (old, new[, count]) -> string

    Return a copy of string S with all occurrences of substring
    old replaced by new.  If the optional argument count is
    given, only the first count occurrences are replaced.
```

Answer (score 62):

```
text = text.replace("very", "not very", 1)
```

The third parameter is the maximum number of occurrences that you want to replace.
From [the documentation for Python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html):

> **string.replace(s, old, new[, maxreplace])**
>   Return a copy of string s with all occurrences of substring old replaced by new. If the optional argument maxreplace is given, the first maxreplace occurrences are replaced.

Answer (score 6):

From http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/string-methods.html :

> **replace( old, new[, count])**
>       Return a copy of the string with all occurrences of substring old replaced by new. If the optional argument count is given, only the
>   first count occurrences are replaced.

I didn't try but I believe it works