# trying to replace string in text file, x lines down from unique line

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, file

i'm trying to replace a string in a text file, the same string exists in other places but im only trying to change the string that is a few lines down from a unique line in the file

below i have code which searches for the unique line, then from that line im searching down x amount of times until i reach the line i need.
i replace the line then it will continue until the range has ended or if it hit another unique line (which is just a '}'),

its working somewhat but its replacing all the strings with the value rather than just the one i want

heres my code:

```
lines = filedata.split("\n")
for line in lines:
  if line == 'unique line':
    for i in range(50):
       if lines[lines.index(line) + i].startswith(' linetoreplace'):
                        filedata = filedata.replace(lines[lines.index(line) + i], 'newstring')
       if lines[lines.index(line) + i].startswith('}'):
                       break
```

any help or direction will be appreciated thanks

Comment: What type of file is this?

Comment: You could specify number of occurrences you want to change, just set the count to one: `filedata = filedata.replace(lines[lines.index(line) + i], 'newstring',1)` found here: [Replace first occurrence only of a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6005891/replace-first-occurrence-only-of-a-string)

Comment: To elaborate on my initial question; `}` on its own on a line in a text file makes it seem more like this was JSON than a generic text file, in which case it can be read and processed differently.

Comment: @mimx your solution has worked!! thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could add a break once you are done replacing the line:

```
done_changing = false
for i in range(50):

    if lines[lines.index(line) + i].startswith(' linetoreplace'):
                        filedata = filedata.replace(lines[lines.index(line) + i], 'newstring')
                        done_changing = True
                        break
    if done_changing:
        break
```

This way, you will exit the loop after replacing your one line, and leave the other lines unchanged.

Comment: thanks for your response, unfortunately its still the same issue

Comment: I have made a few changes, which should fix your problem! @ECM

Comment: Note in Python, bools are `True` and `False`, you currently have invalid syntax. I also don't understand the need for `done_changing = false` on every loop and multiple `break`s?

Comment: @roganjosh made those fixes! the first  break is to get out of `for i in range(50)` and the second one is to get out of `for line in lines`

Comment: @ECM I hope you didn't run into the errors roganjosh pointed out!