# remove string characters after first instance in python

Tags: python, string, replace

I think this should be pretty simple, but its a friday afternoon and my brain isnt in gear clearly.

I'm writing a small file parse, and the code below turns a set of strings in to a dataframe, splitting the strings up.

Here are some example strings:

```
1. NC_002523_1  Serratia entomophila plasmid pADAP, complete sequence.

2. NZ_CM003366_0    Pantoea ananatis strain CFH 7-1 plasmid CFH1-7plasmid2, whole genome shotgun sequence.

3. NZ_CP014491_0    Escherichia coli strain G749 plasmid pG749_3, complete sequence.

4. NC_015062_0  Rahnella sp. Y9602 plasmid pRAHAQ01, complete sequence.
```

I hadn't anticipated the `.` after `sp` in the 4th entry, and as you can see in the code below, I split on the `.` to get the first integer for the rank. Consequently I get a ValueError, that there were more columns than expected.

```
# Define the column headers for the section since the file's are too verbose and ambiguous
SigHit.Columns = ["Rank", "ID", "Description"]

# Store the table of loci and associated data (tab separated, removing last blank column.

# Use StringIO object to imitate a file, which means that we can use read_table and have the dtypes
# assigned automatically (necessary for functions like min() to work correctly on integers)

SigHit.Table = pd.read_table(
               io.StringIO(u'\n'.join([row.rstrip('.') for row in sighits_section])),
               sep='\.|\t',
               engine='python',
               names=SigHit.Columns)
```

The simplest solution for this that I can think of (until some other edge case breaks it), is to replace every `.` except the first occurrence. How can this be done?

I see that there is a `maxreplace` [argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6005891/replace-first-occurrence-only-of-a-string/6005896) to `.replace`, but this would do the opposite of what I want, and would only replace the first instance.

Any suggestions? (More robust parsing approaches also a valid option, but the less I have to change the code the better).

Comment: is your `1.` etc followed by a tab or a space?

Comment: You could [`split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split) your data by the first 2 white spaces. `row.split(None,2)` instead of `row.rstrip`. This would separate on both spaces and tab characters into lists of length 3

Comment: `1.` is followed by a space, the alphanumeric ID is then followed by a tab before the Description (I didn't write the software that output the file :P )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a positive lookbehind to ensure the dot is preceded by a digit - `sep='(?<=\d)\.|\t'`

For example:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

columns = ["Rank", "ID", "Description"]

sighits_section = '''1. NC_002523_1\tSerratia entomophila plasmid pADAP, complete sequence.
2. NZ_CM003366_0\tPantoea ananatis strain CFH 7-1 plasmid CFH1-7plasmid2, whole genome shotgun sequence.
3. NZ_CP014491_0\tEscherichia coli strain G749 plasmid pG749_3, complete sequence.
4. NC_015062_0\tRahnella sp. Y9602 plasmid pRAHAQ01, complete sequence.'''.splitlines()

tab = pd.read_table(io.StringIO(u'\n'.join([row.rstrip('.') for row in sighits_section])),
                    sep='(?<=\d)\.|\t',
                    engine='python',
                    names=columns)

print(tab)
```

prints

```
   Rank              ID                                        Description
0     1     NC_002523_1  Serratia entomophila plasmid pADAP, complete s...
1     2   NZ_CM003366_0  Pantoea ananatis strain CFH 7-1 plasmid CFH1-7...
2     3   NZ_CP014491_0  Escherichia coli strain G749 plasmid pG749_3, ...
3     4     NC_015062_0  Rahnella sp. Y9602 plasmid pRAHAQ01, complete ...
```

For extra safety, you might want to add the space in as your separator alongside the dot - `sep='(?<=\d)\.\s|\t'` - to mitigate in case you have e.g. `10.1` in your descriptions somewhere. This isn't bombproof by any means.

Safer yet - seeing as you're processing your data one line at a time, you can add in an assertion that the digit is the first character in the string too with `sep='(?<=^\d)\.\s|\t'`. However, this will crash on digits higher than 10.

Comment: This looks by far the most robust so far. There should be no reason for decimal numbers to creep in (to a non-malformed file anyway). Bonus points for not requiring much of a change to the code either haha

Comment: @JoeHealey thanks - I've added in another modification for ensuring the digit is at the start of the string - may be the safest yet, but it depends on how many results you get

Comment: Addressing the last little update, yes, the digits can go higher than 10. In theory, any integer is valid, in practice it's unlikely to be greater than 200-300.

Answer (score 1):

**Naive Approach**

replace every `.` except the first occurrence

```
line = "4. NC_015062_0  Rahnella sp. Y9602 plasmid pRAHAQ01, complete sequence."
count = line.count(".")
line = line[::-1].replace(".", "", count-1)[::-1]
```

here is a one liner

```
row[::-1].replace(".","",row.count(".")-1)[::-1]
```