# Remove only one character from a string which has that character repeated more times

Tags: python-2.7

I want to turn "bcdaba" to "bcdba" in python. How can i do that? I tried
 `string = "bcdaba"
new_string = string.replace(string[3],'')` when i print new_string it gave me`"bcdb"`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replace first occurence of string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628618/replace-first-occurence-of-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give str.replace() an additional count parameter:

```
>>> string = 'bcdaba'
>>> string.replace('a', '', 1)
'bcdba'
```

For more information, please read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace).