# replace the first occurrence of a string element in list

Tags: python, string, list

I need to change the first occurrence of a `1` into a `0` for each element of a string in list, but it changes everything:

```
a, b = input().split()
a = int(a)
d=[]
for x in range(1,a+1):
    globals()['side%s' % x] = input("Enter something: ")
    d.append(globals()['side%s' % x])

d = [s.replace('1', '0') for s in d]


print(d)
```

Example:

```
4 1 // 4 number of inputs, 1 - number of possible changes to string

0101
0010
0100
1000
```

need to be

```
0001
0000
0000
0000
```

Comment: Can you better explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you only want to replace the first occurence of a `1` with `0` and leave the other occurences unchanged?

Comment: Yes, only one occurence in each item

Comment: @Bad.coder This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628618/replace-first-occurrence-of-string-in-python. Answer: `replace()` takes an optional third argument, the maximum number of times to replace. For example, `replace('1', '0', 1)` will perform the replacement on only the first instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you want `x` number of occurrence to be replaced, the replace function offers this `string.replace(s, old, new[, maxreplace])`, you might want to pass on `b` which is the `maxreplace`  as the third parameter.

```
a, b = input().split()
a = int(a)
d=[]
for x in range(1,a+1):
    globals()['side%s' % x] = input("Enter something: ")
    d.append(globals()['side%s' % x])

d = [s.replace('1', '0', int(b)) for s in d] # maxreplace will be b only


print(d)
```