# Is there any method to replace space with multiple characters?

Tags: python, string

Example:

Input : `"Base derived derived You are great"`

Output: `"Base->derived:derived You are great"`

Here, the first two spaces are replaced with `->` and `:` respectively, the rest of the string remains the same.

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: Think the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628618/replace-first-occurrence-of-string-in-python might solve this.

Comment: I am new to python, so wondering if any options available in python or not. I have to perform the operations in file line by line,

Comment: Yes, there are @PrinceCady ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing fancy, but if it's a one-off application, this would do the trick, using the Python [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split) method to create a list, splitting the string into three chunks on the first two spaces, then create a new string with those three chunks separated by `'->'` and `':'`.

```
your_string  = "Base derived derived You are great"
split_string = your_string.split(maxsplit=2)
result = f"{split_string[0]}->{split_string[1]}:{split_string[2]}"
```

As suggested in comments by @yatu, this can be reduced to a single statement using the [*-operator](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) to unpack the list:

```
result = '{}->{}:{}'.format(*your_string.split(maxsplit=2))
```

result in both cases:

```
'Base->derived:derived You are great'
```

Comment: `maxsplit` might be useful here

Comment: Also, you might want to add as a more concise alternative `'{}->{}:{}'.format(*s.split(maxsplit=2))`