# How to replace first occurrence of string in Java

Tags: java, string, replace

I want to replace first occurrence of String in the following.

```
String test = "see Comments, this is for some test, help us"
```

**If test contains the input as follows it should not replace

1. See Comments, (with space at the end)
2. See comments,
3. See Comments**

I want to get the output as follows,

```
Output: this is for some test, help us
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: You can goolge-search directly your question, or shift your eyes a little bit to the right of this comment and check the RELATED questions...

Comment: Or you could look at the documentation of [`String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) and find `replaceFirst()`...

Comment: Google will tell you how to replace the first occurrence of a REGEX, not a string.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

You can use [`replaceFirst(String regex, String replacement)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method of String.

Comment: This is for REGEXes not, Strings.

Comment: @Sridhar-Sarnobat this is understood by the parameters I have mentioned in the Answer I guess? And that's how it is supposed to be used. .

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately most readers who've upvoted came looking for the answer you gave rathar than what the OP asked (and what I was looking for).

Comment: This might be for regex, but will work even if you give a String instead of a builtup regex. I just tested. So the above discuss confuses people who see this. The answer is perfect.

Comment: What if you are trying to replace a string that contains `-`?

Comment: @Sridhar-Sarnobat it did work with hyphens `-` as well, just checked right now. Please test yourself and let me know for any issues, I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Sridhar-Sarnobat when the search string contains pattern characters that are not supposed to be interpreted, you may filter the string through [`Pattern.quote(…)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote-java.lang.String-) first. Though, it might be more efficient to use `Pattern.compile(searchString, Pattern.LITERAL).matcher(input) .replaceAll(replacement)` then…

Answer (score 23):

You should use already tested and well documented libraries in favor of writing your own code.

```
org.apache.commons.lang3.
  StringUtils.replaceOnce("coast-to-coast", "coast", "") = "-to-coast"
```

## Javadoc

- https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#replaceOnce-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-

There's even a version that is case insensitive (which is good).

## Maven

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.7</version>
</dependency>
```

## Credits

My answer is an augmentation of: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10861856/714112

Comment: I appreciate ur answer but because replaceFirst in String class is for regex.  But just for one simple string replacement , I have to introduce a new library in my project. not worth .. any alternatives?

Comment: Yeah true, dynamically linked libraries are a pain. You could just copy and paste the library source code.

Answer (score 21):

You can use following statement to replace first occurrence of literal string with another literal string:

```
String result = input.replaceFirst(Pattern.quote(search), Matcher.quoteReplacement(replace));
```

However, this does a lot of work in the background which would not be needed with a dedicated function for replacing literal strings.

Comment: This is the best answer, because it also handles regex characters and it not relies on external libs.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work, try this:
`"I want to earn in euro!".replaceFirst(Pattern.quote("euro"), "$");`

Comment: @FilipStachowiak fixed it.

Answer (score 14):

Use [`substring(int beginIndex)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29):

```
String test = "see Comments, this is for some test, help us";
String newString = test.substring(test.indexOf(",") + 2);
System.out.println(newString);
```

**OUTPUT:**

> this is for some test, help us

Comment: Wait, what if the string you want to replace isn't at the beginning of the input string?

Answer (score 3):

You can use following method.

```
public static String replaceFirstOccurrenceOfString(String inputString, String stringToReplace,
        String stringToReplaceWith) {

    int length = stringToReplace.length();
    int inputLength = inputString.length();

    int startingIndexofTheStringToReplace = inputString.indexOf(stringToReplace);

    String finalString = inputString.substring(0, startingIndexofTheStringToReplace) + stringToReplaceWith
            + inputString.substring(startingIndexofTheStringToReplace + length, inputLength);

    return finalString;

}
```

Following [link](http://self-learning-java-tutorial.blogspot.in/2017/04/replace-first-occurrence-of-string-in.html) provide examples for replacing first occurrence of string using with and without regular expressions.

Answer (score -1):

Use String replaceFirst to swap the first instance of the delimiter to something unique:

```
String input = "this=that=theother"
String[] arr = input.replaceFirst("=", "==").split('==',-1);
String key = arr[0];
String value = arr[1];
System.out.println(key + " = " + value);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also use this method in node.js;

```
public static String replaceFirstOccurance(String str, String chr, String replacement){
    String[] temp = str.split(chr, 2);
    return temp[0] + replacement + temp[1];
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work, `split` works on regex-es.