# How to remove > tag from string in java

Tags: java, regex

I have the following string.
`"Christmas is a very expensive> time of year for most> people so the <br/>Christmas> bazaar is an <b>opportunity</b> for parents to indulge their offspring and buy lots> of small items> as either presents or <b>stocking fillers</b> .|Trust me, it's not easy scooping up gift votives and <b>stocking stuffers</b>"`.

Now I want to remove only `">"` from the strings that ended with with words only not the html tags such as `"<br/> or <b"`

If I use `String.replace("\\>","")` then it remove all the `>` tag from the string.

How can achieve that ?

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided a full example text that shows the false positives that are being removed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace first occurrence of string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10897470/how-to-replace-first-occurrence-of-string-in-java)

Comment: Add in the expected output as well.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the following code suit your need:

```
    String[] split = "This is test string> <br></br>".split(">");

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (String it : split) {
        if(it.contains("<")) {
            it += ">";
        }

        sb.append(it);
    }

    String result = sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use String.replace("string>", "string") to achieve the result. If this doesn't solve your problem please give more details.

Comment: Let's not rush to give the solution without even getting the entire picture of the question.

Comment: Ok, I appreciate the input :)

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to remove the first occurrence of `">"` , use replacefirst(regex,"new-value");

```
System.out.println("This istest string> <br></br>".replaceFirst(">",""));
```

Output:

```
This istest string <br></br>
```

EDIT: Per your comment,"but i need to replace all of the ">" that ended with word from the string".

Use "`positive lookbehind`"

`(?<=String)>` (positive lookbehind) matches the > (and only the >) in `string>`, but does not match somethingelse>.

```
System.out.println("This istest string> <br></br>".replaceFirst("(?<=string)>",""));
```

Comment: Thank you,i know it,but i need to replace all of the ">" that ended with word from the string.