# how to use useDelimiter() once?

Tags: java

I have this code for example

```
 String input = "1 fish 2 fish red fish blue fish";  
 Scanner s = new Scanner(input).useDelimiter("fish");
```

Output:

```
1 
2
red
blue
```

Expected output:

```
1 
2
fish
red
fish
blue
fish
```

using the same useDelimiter without breaking

Comment: Your code doesn't output anything, but obviously you just have to change the delimiter after reading the amount of data with it that you want.

Answer (score 3):

You can reset delimiter by  `s.useDelimiter(" ")` after first 2 uses.

```
String input = "1 fish 2 fish red fish blue fish"; 
Scanner s = new Scanner(input).useDelimiter("\\bfish\\b");

System.out.println(s.next()); // first use
System.out.println(s.next()); // second use
s.useDelimiter(" ");          // setting delimiter to <space>
// print the rest
```

Comment: Sorry did not notice `//First Use`

Comment: I found that the second element was `" 2"` so I used `"fish "` as the delimeter

Answer (score 1):

You could first eliminate that first occurrence and then split by spaces if you want that result [replaceFirst(String regex, String replacement)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10897470/how-to-replace-first-occurrence-of-string-in-java/10897513#10897513) and then do the split.

```
String input = "1 fish 2 fish red fish blue fish"; 
Scanner s = new Scanner(input.replaceFirst(" fish", "")).useDelimiter(" ");
```

I found replaceFirst from another question on SO

Comment: The question is *how to use useDelimiter() once?*

Comment: And OP probably doesn't know he can use replaceFirst, so why would you give worse answer if it can be simpler and better?

Comment: Maybe the OP needs to use it as he described, if you are not sure why not drop him a comment asking for more information.  IMO I would just split the String and if `arr[1]` was `"fish"`, then throw it away, but that was not what the OP asked.

Comment: I don't have 50 rep so i can't give him a comment. I would do so otherwise, it's my bad as i didn't mention it in the answer.

Comment: well you could hedge your bets and put both ideas into your answer

Answer (score 0):

```
String input = "1 fish 2 fish red fish blue fish";
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(input).useDelimiter("fish");
System.out.print(scanner.next() + scanner.next());
scanner.useDelimiter(" ");
while (scanner.hasNext()){
        System.out.print(scanner.next() + " ");
}
```

Comment: The question is *how to use useDelimiter() once?*

Answer (score 0):

You are going to do a double read if the delimier is "fish "

```
String input = "1 fish 2 fish red fish blue fish"; 
String delim = "fish ";
Scanner s = new Scanner(input).useDelimiter(delim);

while (s.hasNext ()) {
    System.out.println(s.next());
    if (delim.equals("fish ") && s.hasNext())
        System.out.println(s.next());
    delim = " ";
    s.useDelimiter(delim);
}
```

**output**

```
1 
2 
fish
red
fish
blue
fish
```

In answer to your comment. 
In that case I think you are better off using `String::split` If the Strings in the resultant array start with fish then throw it away/ignore it.

```
String input = "1 2 3 fish1 1 2 3 fish2 1 2 3 fish3 1 2 3 fish1 1 2 3 fish2 1 2 3";
String [] arr = inpit.split (" ");

for (String el : arr) {
    if (el.startsWith("fish")) continue;
    System.out.println (el);
}
```

Comment: what if the initial string was like this? String input = "1 2 3 fish1 1 2 3 fish2 1 2 3 fish3 1 2 3 fish1 1 2 3 fish2 1 2 3......"; I want to store the data inbetween all the fish string for example i want to store 1 2 3 as a string between fish1 and fish2. I could achieve this using useDelimiter(). when I try to use usedelimiter for fish1 for the second time the data is not read. this is my main concern

Comment: In that case I think you are better off using `String::split`  If the Strings in the resultant array start with `fish` then throw it away/ignore it.  See my edited answer